# What are the differences between shoes like the Nike Magistra Obra and Adidas Primeknit FS vs traditional football shoes?

Tags: football, equipment

Apart that the shoes are integrated with socks what else is different?

How should you wear them?

Will they stink like socks?

[For details and pictures click this link](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2014/03/06/nike-magista-adidas-world-cup-boots_n_4910413.html)

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site!!! you are asking about opinions, and that kind of question is not the type we look for.. Please check the faq for how to ask questions on the site.

Comment: @gbianchi I changed the question so it doesnt seem like Im asking for opinions.Can you answer now?

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Perhaps asking what the difference between these types of shoes with traditional types of shoes would not only come across as not opinionated, but also answerable.

Comment: An example of what you may ask: "What are the differences between shoes like the Nike Magistra Obra and Adidas Primeknit FS versus traditional football shoes?" Within the question, you may inquire about the newer shoes promoting or preventing smell.

Comment: @edmastermind29 changed question as you like

Comment: @edmastermind29 changed it again (I can see what the differences are I just care about how you wear them and their smell)